# YouTube's new subscription videos feed stopped working?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, gdata

The feed was working fine until this morning: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/WTIUNewsBreak/newsubscriptionvideos?&v=2

Not sure what else to say, I have looked around to see if it is just downtime/maintenance but couldn't find anything. Worried that these old feeds have been turned off.

Does anyone know what has happened or what my alternatives are?

This allowed me to grab a users public sub feed without the need to log in.

Comment: It is intermittently working now? This is strange.

Comment: I also have problems with this API, I've [submitted a bug here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5215).

Comment: Still having issues with this, any any ideas on alternative methods to get a users sub feed with only JavaScript?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a transient issue with a specific API.

Comment: Not sure if I'm wrong, but now it returns a feed without video entries? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855530/how-to-retrieve-the-recents-video-uploaded-on-friends-channel