# How to retrieve the recents video uploaded on friend's channel?

Tags: youtube-api

Theorically this is the api I need:

```
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_subscriptions#Retrieving_new_subscription_videos
```

In fact, if I click on https://www.youtube.com/my_subscriptions I see the recent video uploaded by friends (subscriptions).

But calling that endpoint (alt=json) I get this:

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "encoding": "UTF-8",
    "feed": {
        "xmlns": "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
        "xmlns$openSearch": "http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/",
        "xmlns$gd": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005",
        "gd$etag": "W/\"CEIMSHwyfSp7I2A9Wh5QGU0.\"",
        "id": {
            "$t": "tag:youtube.com,2008:user:ysWGKld9kilWfiqcfr1pfQ:newsubscriptionvideos"
        },
        "updated": {
            "$t": "2013-11-08T01:23:09.295-08:00"
        },
        "category": [
            {
                "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind",
                "term": "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video"
            }
        ],
        "title": {
            "$t": "New Subscription Videos for Mauro Vicentini"
        },
        "logo": {
            "$t": "http://www.gstatic.com/youtube/img/logo.png"
        },
        "link": [
            {
                "rel": "alternate",
                "type": "text/html",
                "href": "https://www.youtube.com/subscription_center"
            },
            {
                "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed",
                "type": "application/atom+xml",
                "href": "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ysWGKld9kilWfiqcfr1pfQ/newsubscriptionvideos"
            },
            {
                "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch",
                "type": "application/atom+xml",
                "href": "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ysWGKld9kilWfiqcfr1pfQ/newsubscriptionvideos/batch"
            },
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "type": "application/atom+xml",
                "href": "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ysWGKld9kilWfiqcfr1pfQ/newsubscriptionvideos?alt=json&start-index=1&max-results=25"
            },
            {
                "rel": "service",
                "type": "application/atomsvc+xml",
                "href": "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ysWGKld9kilWfiqcfr1pfQ/newsubscriptionvideos?alt=atom-service"
            }
        ],
        "author": [
            {
                "name": {
                    "$t": "YouTube"
                },
                "uri": {
                    "$t": "http://www.youtube.com/"
                }
            }
        ],
        "generator": {
            "$t": "YouTube data API",
            "version": "2.1",
            "uri": "http://gdata.youtube.com"
        },
        "openSearch$totalResults": {
            "$t": 0
        },
        "openSearch$startIndex": {
            "$t": 1
        },
        "openSearch$itemsPerPage": {
            "$t": 25
        }
    }
}
```

where in fact there are not any "videos" feed.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: what would be the expected output

Comment: A feed with the list of the videos. I mean: where are the video I can see on /my_subscriptions?

Comment: Even because what should be the informations stored in this feed? :O

Comment: N.B. `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/default/newsubscriptionvideos?v=2&alt=json` return the same json

Comment: Uhm? No, this returns subscriptions. I need to returns video feeds of the subscripted channels. I.E. this works https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/GoogleDevelopers/newsubscriptionvideos . I don't know why it does not works with my account

Comment: Wait: it works only with videos not old than 1 week? :O

Comment: then you need to implement some sort of pagination the url is already provided to you in the feed /feed/link/@rel=next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this maybe

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/[userID]/subscriptions?v=2&alt=json
or 
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/[userID]/newsubscriptionvideos?v=2&alt=json

dont forget to add your youtube userID which you can find in

https://www.youtube.com/account_advanced

now if you want to display someone else subscriptions but you dont know their userID you may have authenticate using OATH 2.0

or just go with

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/[youtube_username]/newsubscriptionvideos?v=2&alt=json